# Getting App name in XCtest

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

Is there a way to get the name of the app for which we're running the test. Since I have multiple targets, I need to get the name of the app. Currently I only get the name of the test app via Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleName") not the main app's name.

Comment: You can add arguments to Test setting of each target then use NSProcessInfo to detect which target that the test is running on. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271710/programmatically-determine-current-target-run-or-test-in-ios-project

Comment: Sorry thats doesn't help. Anyways thanks for your help.